# Trouble converting a python program to an executable

Tags: python, exe

I created a simple python program stored on desktop. Using CMD, I set the current directory as the one where the file is located.

Then i used pyinstaller MAIN.py (where MAIN is the filename)

[image]

But it's still showing that script is not found.

EDIT: The issue was with the name. 'main' is a reserved keyword/ inbuilt class for python.

Comment: I am not familiar with pyinstaller, but looking at the error message, the command should probably by `pyinstaller MAIN.py`.

Comment: Did you try to enter `MAIN.py`? Here you only write MAIN

Comment: The name main might be conflicting with inbuilt class. Try using another name?

Comment: yes I have tried both MAIN and MAIN.py. In both cases I get same error.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you saved your MAIN.py file with a space after the MAIN? It looks at least on the screenshot like this :). So [MAIN(space).py].

Comment: I resolved the issue - the name should have been changed to something else as it was conflicting with inbuilt 'main' name.